# changing the imageview effect on javafx

Tags: java, javafx, imageview

I'm trying to light up each time the image being pressed and in case if it's been pressed again I want it to go to the original lighting

```
    // Effect To light up the image once it been pressed to green
    Lighting lighting = new Lighting();
    lighting.setDiffuseConstant(1.0);
    lighting.setSpecularConstant(0.0);
    lighting.setSpecularExponent(0.0);
    lighting.setSurfaceScale(0.0);
    lighting.setLight(new Light.Distant(45, 45, Color.GREEN));

    // Effect to show the unavailable images which can't be pressed
    Lighting lighting_red = new Lighting();
    lighting_red.setDiffuseConstant(1.0);
    lighting_red.setSpecularConstant(0.0);
    lighting_red.setSpecularExponent(0.0);
    lighting_red.setSurfaceScale(0.0);
    lighting_red.setLight(new Light.Distant(45, 45, Color.RED));

    // the original effect and the one to change back the green effect once it being pressed again 
    Lighting orginalLighting = new Lighting();
    orginalLighting.setDiffuseConstant(1.0);
    orginalLighting.setSpecularConstant(0.0);
    orginalLighting.setSpecularExponent(0.0);
    orginalLighting.setSurfaceScale(0.0);
    orginalLighting.setLight(new Light.Distant(85, 85,    Color.LIGHTGREY));

    // To initialize the original imageview and set its original effect   
    for(int i = 0;i<30;i++){
    seats[i] = new ImageView(seats_image); 
    seats[i].setEffect(orginalLighting);
    }


   for(int i=0;i<30;i++){
        Node seat = seats[i];
    seat.setOnMouseClicked(e->{
        if(seat.getEffect()!=lighting_red){
        seat.setEffect(lighting);  }

        if(seat.getEffect()==lighting){
           seat.setEffect(orginalLighting);    }
    });     
    }
```

I wanted to change the image effect in case if is not red to green. And if I already press it and I press it again to the original effect but somehow once I press any image nothing change.

Hint: if I remove the second if, the image will change to green if I press it as long as it is not red. But once I added the second if nothing happen at all it seems like every time I press it change to the original which change nothing in the image

Comment: Do not compare objects with `!=` and `==` but with the equals method instead. This might help.

Comment: @hotzst haven't worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is wrong. Your current implementation is:

If the current effect is `originalLighting`, the first `if` condition will be true, so you change the effect to `lighting`. 
Then the second `if` condition will also be true (since the effect is now `lighting`), so you immediately change the effect back to `originalLighting`.

You need something like:

```
if(seat.getEffect() == lighting) {

    seat.setEffect(originalLighting);

} else if (seat.getEffect() == originalLighting) {

   seat.setEffect(lighting);    

}
```

(Note that if you lay your code out properly, these errors are much easier to see and fix.)

Comment: unfortunately I already did this before it's change everything even the lighting_red to orginalLighting and if I press it again to lighting which is already wrong I want the lighting_red to be lighting_red even I press. And  once I press I orginalLighting to be lighting which already accomplish but my problem once I press again the lighting I want it to change to orginalLighting which is not happening once it's being changed to lighting it's never change to orginallighting

Answer (score 0):

Creates a `List<Integer>` to store the ID of each image **depending on the index** and each time you press the image you run a method to check the ID then you make the change depending on the ID and the number of time the image was pressed:

1)-if the image is in the original state, then you increment in the list of 1 and apply the effect.

2)-if the image has already been pressed you decrement by 1 and you apply the effect.

```
//Create and initialize the List with a loop (length 30 images here)
List<Integer> pressCount = new ArrayList<>();
```